# What happens when I load gtag.js twice on my web page?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, double-click-advertising, gtag.js

I use both GA and DCM for tracking events on my webpage. I dynamically create a scripts tag to load gtag.js on my webpages based on some criteria. Now i have a situation when certain criteria matches i have to load only GA and for some other criteria i load only DCM config. But now i have a third condition where both needs to be triggered. So, in my current implementation for the third criteria where both needs to be triggered my loadscript is called twice leading to addition of gtag('js', new Date()); twice into my dataLayer. Not sure what will be the impact of this. Does this mean the second gtag('js', new Date()); overrides the first one when it sends data to GA or DCM? Is there any documentation where i can read more about what happens in this situation?Can anybody please help?